# Facebook posted link crawl

Tags: facebook, web-crawler, facebook-group

Here's a problem: I've got some number of links posted to groups "as is". That posts look like a link, nothing more. Is there a way to make that links crawled to previews, as Facebook automatically does when we share a link or post it with a minor delay? Without re-posting them.

Answer (score 0):

I've had that with slow internet connections or weak devices.
Or you can read this: http://www.robblatt.com/technology/facebook-previews-not-working-heres-a-fix/

Anyhow, if it doesn't show the preview at any try, you should - before trying again - refresh the page, as (mentioned in above link) if it doesn't go the first time, it never will, unless you refresh.
otherwise, did you update the page recently (or was it recently updated)?

**Edit:** try adding this to the end of the link: `?=1`

Comment: Well, my problem is slightly different: I can get a preview while posting a link, but I have a bunch of links that have been already posted without preview. So my question was about updating that links, not re-posting them.